# PHP PDO update query not working but no errors

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to implement a method to update users from the admin page through a form.
I have a generic method `update` because I'm updating my own MVC framework.

```
public function update()
    {
        $tableName = $this->tableName();
        $attributes = $this->attributes();
        $params = array_map(fn($attr) => ":$attr", $attributes);
        $paramsArray = array_combine($attributes, $params);
        $list = [];
        foreach ($paramsArray as $key => $value) {
            $list[] = "$key=$value";
        }
        $primaryKey = $this->primaryKey();
        $primaryValue = $this->{$primaryKey};
        try {
            $statement = self::prepare("UPDATE $tableName SET " . implode(', ', $list) . " WHERE $primaryKey = $primaryValue");
            foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
                $statement->bindValue(":$attribute", $this->{$attribute});
            }
            $statement->execute();
            return true;
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            echo "Check Input Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "</br>";
        }
    }
```

So, this method (with my user) give me this statement :

`'UPDATE users SET firstname=:firstname, lastname=:lastname, email=:email, password=:password, status=:status, type=:type WHERE id = 10'`.

I don't catch any PDOException, but nothing change in my database.

 I setted PDO attributes like that :

`pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Things I checked :

- I dumped this part `$this->{$attribute}` in my foreach and the values I'm getting are fine.
- I've tried to use the statement above directly in PHPMyAdmin and replacing the bind values by the real values and everything works fine.
- I also tried to change the statement to create a mysql query error and I had one.

Maybe I'm missing something from the whole update process but I have a `save` method for database `INSERT` that use kind of the same logic and it works fine.

Comment: Should `$statement->bindValue(":$attribute", $this->{$attribute});` not be `$statement->bindValue(":$attribute", $attribute);`?

Comment: This method is clearly part of a larger whole. That makes it difficult for us to solve your problem, unless it is something obvious. I don't see anything. I mean Prof. Abronsius could be right, but who knows? I did notice you didn't say that you actually checked what the query and values have become, and whether it actually executes. I would expect so, and they are simple checks, so why not do them?

Comment: Make sure the code  actually runs and you provided correct values. There is no magic. ether query executed successfully or there is an error.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware he is obviously not right because $attribute contains the name not value

Comment: @YourCommonSense Well, the object might have properties with `$attribute` names. They are used as property names: `$this->{$attribute}`. I do agree that looks very weird, but who are we to judge?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thanks for your answer. I'm afraid I don't really know how to check what the query and values have become..

Comment: the code should be like this tho https://3v4l.org/3uUP4 not to fix some imaginary error but just for sake of simplicity

Comment: @YourCommonSense thanks as well for your answer. To be honest, I followed 'TheCodeHolic' course to create a PHP MVC framework and I'm trying to implement other methods. So I'm using the logic he used for the other methods

Comment: @NicolasHalberstadt There are many ways to check what PHP actually does. You can simply echo what is happening. You could make your own little log system. The possibilities are endless, just do something that will tell you the query has actually executed. I like Your Common Sense code better: more to the point.